# Trouble with querySelector and nth-child

Tags: css

On this particular [website](https://lojaonline.tim.com.br/celulares/motorola/moto-g6-play-31327#!/controle-2.0gb-fid-novalinha#Indigo), i'm trying to make a query selector to get all the itens inside the div with id='plans-tab'. Here's what i've got so far:

```
document.querySelector('#plans-tab .row .small-12.columns:nth-child(1)')
```

It gets me the first item. But if i try to make

```
document.querySelector('#plans-tab .row .small-12.columns:nth-child(2)')
```

It returns null. Inside that tab, there's about 14-15 items, so it should've worked. What am i doing wrong here??

If the site asks for a zip code, just type 51030560, and it's good to go

Edit: here's a jsfidle with some more html code: https://jsfiddle.net/gz1ht2to/1/

Comment: pls show your HTML codes too

Comment: I've added the web site on the first sentence of the question. It's not a website i made. But here's the link anyway: https://lojaonline.tim.com.br/celulares/motorola/moto-g6-play-31327#!/controle-2.0gb-fid-novalinha#Indigo

Comment: Don't tell people to go to an external site in order to solve your problem; post it in your question itself so as to make a [MCVE]

Comment: Also, your `nth-child(1)` selector returns nothing for me.

Comment: It returns exactly one div. Did you input the zipcode when the website asked?

Comment: `#plans-tab` doesn't even exist on the site

Comment: Edited with a jsfiddle

Comment: `#plans-tab` doesn't even exist in the jsfiddle ......

Comment: Edited the jsfiddle, so it should be ok now

Comment: No, it isn't.  Try again.

Comment: Edited once again, the new link is at the bottom of the question

Answer (score 0):

First of all your website doesn't have the div with the id "#plans-tab", but if I am getting your question right then this might be the solution that you are looking for:

This is just the dummy HTML:

```
<div id="plans-tab">
  <input>
  <button>
  Click
  </button>
  <input>
  <div>

  </div>
</div>

<div id="html-to-display">

</div>
```

This is the jQuery that I used:

```
var variable = $("#plans-tab");
$("#html-to-display").text(variable.html());
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your selector: `#plans-tab .row .small-12.columns:nth-child(2)` finds the first element that is a 2nd child, has class "small-12" and "columns" that is a descendant of an element with class "row" that is a descendant of an element with id "plans-tab".

Paraphrased from your jsfiddle:

```
<div id="plans-tab"> <---- "#plans-tab"
  <div class="hidden" id="current_plan">
    <div class="row"> <---- " .row"
      <div class="small-12 columns">  <---- " .small-12.columns:nth-child(1)"
        <h2>Escolha o seu plano</h2>
        <!-- ngRepeat: planMember in plans -->
        <div data-ng-repeat="planMember in plans" class="ng-scope">
          <div class="plan-container small-12 columns selected" data-ng-class="{&quot;selected&quot;: plan.id == planMember.id}" data-ng-hide="isPortabilityPrePlan(planMember)">
```

I think what you wanted was this: `#plans-tab .row .small-12.columns :nth-child(2)`, which is the first element that is a 2nd child and is a descendant of an element that has class "small-12" and "columns" that is a descendant of an element with class "row" that is a descendant of an element with id "plans-tab".

```
<div id="plans-tab"> <---- "#plans-tab"
  <div class="hidden" id="current_plan">
    <div class="row"> <---- " .row"
      <div class="small-12 columns">  <---- " .small-12.columns"
        <h2>Escolha o seu plano</h2>
        <!-- ngRepeat: planMember in plans -->
        <div data-ng-repeat="planMember in plans" class="ng-scope"> <---- " :nth-child(2)"
          <div class="plan-container small-12 columns selected" data-ng-class="{&quot;selected&quot;: plan.id == planMember.id}" data-ng-hide="isPortabilityPrePlan(planMember)">
```

Only difference is the space, which has semantic value. `"x:y"` == "an x that is a y". `"x :y"` == "an x that has a y"